# Recommended testing frameworks for testing SOAP as well as REST services?

Tags: wcf, testing, rest, soap, soapui

We have several WCF services - some with SOAP endpoints and others that with REST endpoints. There are also some services that have both SOAP and REST endpoint (diff. customer specs/demands). So far when it comes to testing, we've written custom test clients from ground up purely for testing the actual service+endpoints. However, I'm not sure if that's the best approach because we also have to maintain the test applications as a separate 'product'.

Is there any recommended approach to formally test these endpoints and services? Hopefully one framework/pattern that can cover both SOAP as well as REST sides.

Comment: I can't think how else you would test the services, except to call them the way the clients will call them.

Answer (score 3):

[SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/About-SoapUI/features.html) can test both SOAP and REST web services. Check out its other features.

Comment: I'm using WSHttpBinding() which is SOAP 1.2 (kicks in WS-Security). The WCF Test Client (and our custom .NET test clients) perform the SOAP security handshake (4 messages) before the actual message (5th one). SoapUI seems to skip security handshaking and tries the message in cleartext. It fails with `The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/IService/test' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or ...`. How do I setup SoapUI to use security?

Comment: Take a look at the docs: http://www.soapui.org/pdf/soap-and-wsdl/applying-ws-security.pdf

Comment: I wish SoapUI was more idiot proof. Forget Soap1.2 WS-Security (windows auth), I can't even set it up correctly for my no-security REST (POST) API! I think I might stick with Fiddler scripts and our custom in-house test client. It sucks that I can develop a WCF REST(json/pox) + SOAP service but can't even setup the test tool's myriad options to work with it :( ... my fault (?)

Comment: I just used SoapUI to test and build against a SOAP endpoint - it was fantastic.  I didn't use any security, but the fact that SoapUi auto-builds a framework to access and all the SOAP methods so that you can see what's happening realtime and adjust things as neccessary.  It sped up my development considerably.  It even will auto-build a complete testing set that you can use with the load test tool, AND will even create a complete mock suite of the endpoint too!  All from sniffing a little wsdl.  Superfantastic for my needs!

Answer (score 2):

This answer is specific to testing RESTful web services. We use the following tools:

**[RestClient](http://code.google.com/p/rest-client/)** is a Java application to test RESTful webservices.

**curl** - Comes in the Cygwin distribution for windows. You can find linux installables for your flavor of linux here. Sample uses of curl to make REST calls:

```
curl -v http://flickr.com/rogermenezes/photos/61 -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -H 'X-FlickrAPI-Version:1.0' -X DELETE
curl -v http://flickr.com/rogermenezes/albums -H 'Content-Type:application/json' -H 'X- FlickrAPI -Version:1.0' -X POST -d '{"name": "hawaii 2011", "tags": "vacation, hawaii, ", "creation_date": "2012-02-22T13:42Z"}'
```

**Chrome Plugin** - [Advance REST Client](http://restforchrome.blogspot.com/)

You can install this plugin through the Chrome Web Store. You can save past requests and the plugin also maintains a history of previous calls you had made.

**Fiddler2**

Fiddler2 snoops your network traffic. It also provides a way to "reissue and edit" past requests. Here, you can edit your past REST requests and execute them repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the headers section to provide security token. Our services are secured and I use SOAPUI to organize tests